# Making a SlideShow JApplet

Tags: java, swing, japplet

For my class I have to make a SlideShow JApplet. The user will be able to open up to ten pictures of their choice and it will go through them in a slide show with a delay for each one. I got everything working in my code with them being able to bring up the open dialog box to select only image files. But once I started messing with my buildPicturePanel() nothing showed up when I ran the file. Can someone please give me some help with this on what I should change with this or add. Please be descriptive, the book didn't give a good example with images that apply to this.

Here is my code thus far.

```
public class Slideshow extends JApplet  {
   //setting all JItmes along with items for the image and timer
    private JLabel display;
    private JButton open ;
   private  JButton start ;
    private JButton stop ;
    private JPanel picturePanel;
    private JPanel navigationPanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private BufferedImage pics;
    private int counter = 0;
    private ImageIcon[] pictures ;
    private JLabel label;

    int currentImage = -1;
    String images[];
    private Object image;
    File selectedFile;
    String fileName;


  //basically the main method for a JApplet
    public void init() {
        this.setSize(400,500);
        buildNavPanel();
       buildPicturePanel();
        mainPanel();


    }
    //creates the panel that will hold the slide show
    private void buildPicturePanel(){
      try{
          pics = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
      }catch(IOException ex){
          System.out.println("Please open another selection of pictures.");
      }

    }

    //navigation panel where user can hit add, start, stop
    private void buildNavPanel(){
        navigationPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        navigationPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
        open = new JButton("Open Images (Up to 10)");
        start = new JButton ("Start Slide Show");
        stop = new JButton ("Stop Slide Show");
        open.addActionListener(new OpenListener());
        navigationPanel.add(open);
        navigationPanel.add(start);
        navigationPanel.add(stop);



    }

    //main panel holds all panels with location
    private void mainPanel(){
        buildNavPanel();
       buildPicturePanel();
        add(navigationPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(picturePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //shows current picture
    public void showCurrent(){
        display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images[currentImage]));

    }

    //shows next picture
    public void showNext(){
        currentImage = currentImage +1;
        if (currentImage >= images.length){
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        showCurrent();



    }




//this will make the openlistener work
   private class OpenListener implements ActionListener{

   //actionevent for openlistener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
     FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter ("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
     int response = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
     if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
         selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
         fileName = selectedFile.getPath();

    }

    }

}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: You also want to have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: 1) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. 2) Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) The code will need to be fully trusted & 'all permissions' before it can open files from the user's computer.